# Python and initialization of class variables - how to use class method to initialize members?

Tags: python

I want to initialize class member with use class method but not know how to call it.

Can you suggest some solution - maybe it is very trivial but I can not find solution?

This code will not work - I do not why?

```
class X(object):
  @staticmethod
  def __Y():
    return 1

  CONSTANT = __Y()


x = X()
print x.CONSTANT
```

This will work but I need use call method to initialize class members.

```
class X(object):
  CONSTANT = 1

x = X()
print x.CONSTANT
```

---

Note, I am not want initialize object variables but class variable.

Answer (score 7):

Drop the `@staticmethod` decorator and the first approach will work as well. You don't need `staticmethod` just to call a function inside a class statement.

Since that way the function will not be usable when called from class instances, it is an idiom to also remove it after use. In your example:

```
class X(object):
    def __y():
      return 1

    CONSTANT = __y()
    # ... other uses of __y, if any
    del __y
```

To understand why your approach didn't work, consider what `staticmethod` does. It wraps a normal function into a [descriptor object](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) that, when retrieved from the class, produces the original function unchanged, i.e. without the usual "bound method" semantics. (Retrieving a normal `def` function from an instance or a class would get you a bound method that automagically inserts `self` as the first argument.)

However, the descriptor returned by `staticmethod` is itself not callable, its sole function is to produce the callable object when accessed through the class or instance. [Proposals](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2006-March/061948.html) to make the `staticmethod` descriptor callable were rejected because such use of `staticmethod` is [erroneous in the first place](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2006-March/062451.html).

Comment: Just curious, Dropping `@staticmethod` will turn `def __Y()` to `def __Y(self)`, right? How is it possible to call the method without instantiating the class? In this case, `CONSTANT = __Y(X())`?

Comment: @Bibhas No, the insertion of `self` only happens when you access `__Y` through class or instance. If you call it from the class definition, a `def` is just a `def`. As no magic happens in the first place, you don't need `@staticmethod` to prevent it from happening.

Comment: @Bibhas Do call `x.__Y()` where x is some instantiated object. Instead, just call `__Y()` in the class definition will not lead `__Y(self)`.

Comment: Oh. It's just another function. It doesn't become a method. Not accessible from the instance.

Comment: Doesn't calling `x.__Y()` pass `x` as the first argument always?

Comment: It is working when I was removed @staticmethod. Not care that this function can not be used inside instances whatever it needs be solved too.