# Class variables and static methods in Python

Tags: python-2.7

In Python 2.7, I am trying to set a class variable based on static methods.

```
class Params(object):

    DEFAULT_PATH = Params._set_default_path()

    @staticmethod
    def _set_default_path():
        return os.path.expanduser(
            "~/prod") if Params._is_host_in_prod() else os.path.expanduser(
            "~/qa")

    @staticmethod
    def _is_host_in_prod():
       return True # always prod, example code
```

when I execute the code, I get `NameError: name 'Params' is not defined`, what's the Pythonic way to do it?

Comment: I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16456924/12946233 What do you think about it?

Comment: I think this is helpful